# How can I set a controller's model without triggering an observer?

Tags: ember.js

Given I have this:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  autosave: function(){
    //stuff
  }.observes('content.text', 'content.colour', 'content.webfont')
});
```

How can I set SomeController's model in a route WITHOUT triggering autosave?

Comment: Hi @Michael. I have answered your question. Just to know, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am using epf, and the observer implements autosave. However, due to an open issue in epf, I end up having to reset the model in the observer, which leads to an infinite loop of infinite loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emberjs doesn't have suport to suspend observers at least [in public api](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/bc64a09a0c8ee38b6fdf06e100f8c461894c02af/packages/ember-metal/lib/observer.js#L73).

My approach to that problems is to create a flag:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  _suspendAutosave: false,
  suspendAutosave: function(fn) {
    this.set('_suspendAutosave', true);
    fn();
    this.set('_suspendAutosave', false);
  },
  autosave: function(){
    if (this.get('_suspendAutosave')) { return; }  
    // some code ...
  }.observes('content.text', 'content.colour', 'content.webfont')
});
```

At some place:

```
controller.suspendAutosave(function() {
  controller.set('content.text', 'foo');
});
```

This isn't cool, but is the only way that I know. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use: Ember.removeObserver() and Ember.addObserver() methods.